# spark-submit command including mysql connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have an scala object file which internally queries mysql table does a join and writes data to s3, tested my code in local it runs perfectly fine. but when i submit it to cluster it throws below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
>     at QuaterlyAudit$.main(QuaterlyAudit.scala:51)  at
>   QuaterlyAudit.main(QuaterlyAudit.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

below is my sparksubmit command:

```
nohup spark-submit --class QuaterlyAudit --master yarn-client --num-executors 8 
--driver-memory 16g --executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 10 /mypath/campaign.jar &
```

i am using sbt, i included mysql connector in sbt assembly, Below is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "mobilewalla"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.6.0" intransitive(),
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.37")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) =>
    xs.map(_.toLowerCase) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) |
       ("index.list" :: Nil) |
       ("dependencies" :: Nil) |
       ("license" :: Nil) |
       ("notice" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first // was 'discard' previousely
}
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
assemblyJarName in assembly := "campaign.jar"
```

i also tried with:

```
nohup spark-submit --driver-class-path /mypath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar 
--class QuaterlyAudit --master yarn-client --num-executors 8 --driver-memory   16g 
--executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 10 /mypath/campaign.jar &
```

but still no luck, what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious reason the Spark is not able to get the JDBC JAR. There are few work around by which it can be fixed. No doubt many people faced this issue . It is due to Jar is not getting uploaded to driver and executor.

1. You might want to assembly you application with your build manager (Maven,SBT) thus you'll not need to add the dependecies in your `spark-submit` cli.
2. You can use the following option in your `spark-submit` cli : 
   `--jars $(echo ./lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')`
3. You can also try to configure these 2 variables : `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf file and specify the value of these variables as the path of the jar file. Ensure that the same path exists on worker nodes.

Comment: it got fixed by addition of `.option("driver" , "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` to `sqlContext.read` command i used `nohup spark-submit --class QuaterlyAudit --master yarn-client --num-executors 8 
--driver-memory 16g --executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 10 /mypath/campaign.jar &` command and it worked

Comment: You have added the jar during the  build only .using build manager . Thats also possibly way which i have already mentioned in point 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify packages like this:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4,mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6 your-jar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In your spark submit command you need both params,

1. --jars
2. --driver-class-path

--jars argument will put jar in each cluster.
--driver-class-path will tell application to actually use it.

> nohup spark-submit --driver-class-path
> /mypath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar --jars
> /mypath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar
> --class QuaterlyAudit --master yarn-client --num-executors 8 --driver-memory   16g
> --executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 10 /mypath/campaign.jar &